# geoscatter plot on plotly with a shape file

Tags: matplotlib, plotly-dash, geopandas, shapefile

I need to plot Italy's map with points on it, using plotly and dash libraries.
Actually, I've done that using go.scattergeo. But it does not show the borders of provinces. (Generally the quality of map is less than shape file that I have)

I also succeed to plot shape file with scatter points in matplotlib. But I have to plot it in plotly to use in my dashboard.

Is there any way to have a scatter plot with a shape file in plotly?

To have Ideas what's the target I post the photos:
This is my dash:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXuJD.png)

This is shape file with scatter plots on matplotlib:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRdIR.png)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you should convert your *shapefile* to a *geojson* format, or just download a *geojson*-file with your desired resolution.

You could then use `go.Scattermapbox` to plot your scatter-plot over the map from your *geojson*-file. I downloaded a *geojson*-file from *github* for the example below (such that it should work if you run the code).
The image from my example code ends up looking like this:
[image: Scatterplot over Italian regions]

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json

with urlopen('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openpolis/geojson-italy/master/geojson/limits_IT_regions.geojson') as response:
    counties = json.load(response)
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(go.Scattermapbox(
    mode = "markers",
    lon = [12.5], lat = [41.9],
    marker = {'size': 5, 'color': ["red"]}))

fig.update_layout(
    mapbox = {
        'style': "white-bg",
        'center': { 'lon': 12.5, 'lat': 41.9},
        'zoom': 4, 'layers': [{
            'source': counties,
            'type':'fill', 'below':'traces','color': 'grey', 'opacity' : 0.2}],
    },
    margin = {'l':0, 'r':0, 'b':0, 't':0})

fig.show()
```